# AWS CrossAccount Pipeline build from Codecommit source code

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I am currently in confusion for a rather complex but yet brilliant way of managing CI/CD flows with with AWS Multi-account strategy.

AWS accounts: A(DevOps) B(development)

This whole process is build upon Cloudformation templates. My questions is that I want to build a docker image from the source code of Account A to account B. But how do I get cross access to the codecommit repository from Account A?

So the source code is in Account A. The pipeline is working and building fine into Account B But the CI/CD flow can't continue here as the source code is in Account A Not sure if its possible to crate the build flow from the source code in account A

Alternative: Create the docker image in Account A where the source code is and push the Image to ECR in account B.

I rather do the first approach as it in my opinion more convenient as the stack can just be deleted within the Dev account(B) and then the whole pipeline is deleted without the DevOps (account A) need to interfere.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to get the source and use it in another account.

I have this experience when working cross-account codepipelines using KMS and storing the output artifact in S3.

I followed this link and hope its helpful for you.

[Building a Secure Cross-Account Continuous Delivery Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/)

[Video version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFQQkoO9kEc)

Also, pull image from ECR stay in account A into Account B is possible.

[allow a secondary account to push or pull images in my Amazon ECR image repository](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/secondary-account-access-ecr)